# Ubuntu brightness reset after reboot thinkpad E14

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad

In my laptop (lenovo thinkpad E14) I have installed ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I am starting the ubuntu the brightness is set to max. Again I have to adjust using Fn + F5 to adjust. Its Ryzen 3 processor

Is there any permanent solution for this ?